# Cannot find type - with mono FastCGI4 and ubuntu

Tags: mono, fastcgi, lighttpd

I think I've been searching around the web for about 2 hours now (neglecting Facebook..) and I can't find a solution for the life of me!

I have a simple web app -:

```
Default.aspx
Global.ascx
bin
```

but for some reason when I deploy to my server I simply get the dreaded "can't find type" error, for things that are clearly in my bin folder...

```
"Parser Error

Description: Error parsing a resource required to service this request. Review your source file and modify it to fix this error.

Parser Error Message: Cannot find type PTest.Global

Source Error:

Line 1: <%@ Application Inherits="PTest.Global" %>

Source File: /home/stu/www/aspx/Global.asax  Lines: 1, 1"
```

funny thing is, if I run a simple page, with inline C# it runs fine and does the job - only compiled stuff fails... :/

If it helps, its a 4.0 app (not MVC..) running on a Lighttpd server using FASTCGI.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Where is your PTest.Global class/app defined?

Comment: Its defined in PTest.Global.ascx.cs (PTest is my app name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting this error as well and found [this page](http://www.cuyahoga-project.org/home/forum.aspx?g=posts&t=905).

Turns out I hadn't coppied my bin/ directory over to my webserver. When I copied that directory over it started working. YMMV

Comment: Thanks for that - But I can assure that my bin directory is definately deployed! I'll double my settings tonight!

Comment: I'm not sure how (I'm guessing it could have been a casing issue in my config file - but this has now started working (I also remove my path mappings) and re-deployed again (for the Nth time!).